# Flask/Python - How can I render this data in a text-form instead of list

Tags: python, url, flask, request

I am trying to get data from an calendar URL using flask. I have an URL which I am requesting data from. I am getting the output in a list which is not what I want. I want the data from the URL to be rendered in a text-form (like https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) so I can edit the results I get. Right now I can't edit it since its in a

list, like this word.

I want it to be something like this "Key : value (the value is in a text-form)".

My current code iterates through the data and renders it in a list instead of a form.

```
import requests
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask('__name__')

def get_json(id):
url =             'https://cloud.timeedit.net/ltu/web/schedule1/{0}.json'.format(id)
r = requests.get(url)
return r.json()['reservations']


@app.route('/')
def index():
reservations = get_json('ri107357055Z76Q506656Q65yZ075W2313Y63Q5Q')
return render_template('reservations.html', reservations=reservations)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

HTML:

```
e {% for reservation in reservations %}
<ul>
{% for key in reservation %}
    {% if key == 'columns' %}
    <li>{{ key }} -</li>
    <ul>
        {% for item in reservation[key] %}
            {% if item %}
                <li>{{ item }}</li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <li>{{ key }} - {{ reservation[key] }} </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

see if this works for you,

#### Only need to make changes in the html file

```
{% for reservation in reservations %}
<ul>
{% for key in reservation %}
    {% if key == 'columns' %}
    <li>{{ key }} -</li>
    <ul>
        {% for item in reservation[key] %}
            {% if item %}
                <li>{{ item }}</li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
       <form action="/action_page.php">
          {{ key }} - s <input type="text" name="lname", value="{{ reservation[key] }}"><br>
      </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
<hr>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for @iamklaus thanks a lot.

Comment: now the question is how I can use "dynamic" urls which are not hard coded.

If I for example want a button called "Insert URL" which can take an URL and take the data and output it just like we did above?  I guess it would work like a parameter? Do you have any clues?

The only thing that differs from the different URL's is the part after "timeedit.net/ltu/web/schedule" https://cloud.timeedit.net/ltu/web/schedule1/ri107357055Z76Q506656Q65yZ075W2313Y63Q5Q.html

Comment: was not able to tag you in the comment above

Comment: Travelling..so won't be able to help now...but it's very easy do..I suggest to Google, somebody might have already solved this problem

Comment: Np, i understand. I am a noob as you can see which makes my google-skills really bad as well, only know how to google in java hehe :D

Thanks again! @iamklaus